# Double to QString and save in QJsonDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qjson

I need to save values ​​below pre-set levels, using `QJsonDocument`.
I have the following example of code:

```
(...) 
gameLevels= {3.67, 7.43, 9.76};
while(gameLevels[i] <= x) 
{     
   for(...)
   {
    //do something and calculate auxPoints.
   }
   QString sGL = QString::number(gameLevels[i]);
   QString below = "below";
   QString points = "pts";
   instantPowerPoints.insert(below + sGL+ points , auxPoints);
   i++;
   (...)
}        
emit saveData(QJsonDocument(instantPowerPoints));'
```

It should save something like:

```
"below3.67pts":2
"below7.43pts":6
"below9.76pts":10
```

But instead is saving:

```
"below3":Object
   "67pts":2
"below7":Object
   "43pts":6
"below9":Object
   "76pts":10
```

I get the problem is how I save the array of doubles `gameLevels`. But I really need to have the number with the dot save as a string. Is there another way to save the string like this without automatically creating the object?

I am using C++ in QTCreator.

Comment: What kind of object is `instantPowerPoints`? and what happens in the slot(s) connected to `saveData`?

Answer (score 0):

This should to the work

`instantPowerPoints.insert(QString("%1 %2 %3").arg(below).arg(sGL).arg(points), auxPoints);`